# Return generated geometry using a QGIS aggregate function

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have a "Phenomenon" table, listing the location (Province, or admin level 3 in this case) of where a certain phenomenon was observed. I would like to return the centroid geometry from a Provinces polygon layer to this Phenomenon table using a QGIS aggregate function.

I have standardized columns with shared PCodes (**admin3Pcode** OR **adm3Pcode**) between Provinces and Phenomenon tables.

I am not getting any output from the following aggregate function and I don't understand why.

```
aggregate(
 layer:= 'adm3_polys', 
 aggregate:='array_agg',
 expression:=geom_to_wkt(centroid(@geometry)),
 filter:='adm3Pcode'= attribute(@parent, 'admin3Pcode')
 )
```

Comment: First, fix the double quoting in the filter:  ```filter:="adm3Pcode"= attribute(@parent, 'admin3Pcode')```. Single quote is used to define a constant string, double quoting refers to a field.

Comment: Thanks for this.  
I'm not sure I'm using the correct aggregate function. I think the 'collect' aggregate might be the way to return a geometry.  

But then I don't know what to put in the expression. 
I'm using GeoPackage - one geometry table and one non-geometry table.  

```aggregate(
 layer:= ''adm3_polys'',
 aggregate:=collect(centroid($geometry)),
 expression:=(centroid($geometry)),
 filter:="admin3Pcode"=attribute(@parent,"admin3Pcode"))```

Answer (score 2):

You can put the geometry in a field, but it will be more complex. I suggest you to create two fields: **x_centroid** and **y_centroid**.

Try this:

To calculate x:

```
aggregate(
    layer:= 'adm3_polys', 
    aggregate:='array_agg',
    expression:=x(centroid(@geometry)),
    filter:="adm3Pcode"= attribute(@parent, 'admin3Pcode')
)[0]
```

To calculate y:

```
aggregate(
    layer:= 'adm3_polys', 
    aggregate:='array_agg',
    expression:=y(centroid(@geometry)),
    filter:="adm3Pcode"= attribute(@parent, 'admin3Pcode')
)[0]
```

And be careful with the double quotation, it's a little bit confusing. For example: here `filter:="adm3Pcode"= attribute(@parent, 'admin3Pcode'))` you use double quotes for `"adm3Pcode"` because we are referring a field, but here `attribute(@parent, 'admin3Pcode')` you use single quotes because the `attribute()` function takes the name of the field as a string.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think it's really close but I don't have it working just yet. I'm writing to the two text fields, because we're casting each coordinate to WKT. But for some reason, there's just no output.  

Why do you use the '`y( )` around the larger aggregate function?

Comment: `x` and `y` are the functions for extracting coordinates

Comment: Sorry if it's too late, yes you are right there was an error in my answer, I updated with the expressions fixed.